# c++ - Utilización de la función fseek

Tags: c++

Tengo un consulta sobre la función fseek. Todo surge a partir de ver la siguiente sentencia:

```
fseek(f, (-1)*sizeof(int),SEEK_CUR);
```

La cuál yo pensé que generaría error. Sin embargo veo que se puede multiplicar por un número negativo. Pero ¿Qué es lo que el compilador interpreta exactamente? ¿Vuelve al inicio del archivo?

El código completo es el siguiente.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    int x;
    int y = 1000;
    f = fopen("prueba.laquequieras","wb");
    int vec[] = {91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100};
    fwrite(vec, sizeof(int), 10, f);
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("prueba.laquequieras", "rb+");
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
    fread(&x, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fread(&x, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fread(&x, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fseek(f, (-1)*sizeof(int),SEEK_CUR); //Duda.
    fwrite(&y, sizeof(int),1,f);
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
    fread(&x, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        cout << x << ";";
        fread(&x, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

y el output es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Donde se movería el cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función [`std::fseek`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fseek) forma parte de las librerías del lenguaje C portadas a C++, está incluida en la cabecera [`<cstdio>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdio) que es el equivalente C++ de `<stdio>`, la cabecera de Entrada/Salida de C.

La función `std::fseek` tiene los siguientes parámetros de entrada:

- Puntero a flujo de archivo de tipo [`std::FILE`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c).
- Desplazamiento (en bytes).
- Posición desde la que contar el desplazamiento.

Así pues, esta llamada:

```
std::fseek(f, (-1)*sizeof(int), SEEK_CUR); //Duda.
```

Se podría traducir como:

> Retrocede un `int` (`(-1)*sizeof(int)`) en el flujo de archifo `f` desde la posición en que el flujo `f` se encuentre actualmente (`SEEK_CUR`).

Comment: Luego cuándo escribe el archivo ¿"Pisa" el valor que estaba en su lugar?. Es por eso que el 93 no sale más. ¿Lo entendí bien?

Comment: Eso mismo interpreto yo en base al código que compartiste :)